# CREATE TABLE permission denied in Azure database 'master'

Tags: android, sql, azure-sql-database

**NOTE:** I can delete the database and can create a table through the shell but when I run a query in my Android Studio to create a table it through permission denied error.

Connection can successfully establish to the database.

I am using Stander S0 tier of Microsoft Azure(Free trail)

**Here is my Code:**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button add;
TextView errorlbl;
EditText name, address, pincode;
Connection connect;
Context context;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
Statement st;
String ipaddress, db, username, password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);



    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
    errorlbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblerror);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtname);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtaddress);
    pincode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpincode);

    connect = ConnectionHelper();

    if (connect != null) {
        System.out.println ("Connet is NOT NULL");

        // Drop previous table of same name if one exists.
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = connect.createStatement ();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        try {
            statement.execute ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS studentRecord;");
            System.out.println ("Finished dropping table (if existed).");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        // Create table.
        try {
            statement.execute ("CREATE TABLE studentRecord (Name VARCHAR(50), Address VARCHAR(50), Pincode INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);");
            System.out.println ("Created table.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e ("Database not created", e.getMessage ());
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println ("Connet is NULL");
    }

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                st = connect.createStatement();
                preparedStatement = connect
                        .prepareStatement("insert into studentRecord (Name,Address,Pincode) values ('"
                                + name.getText().toString()
                                + "','"
                                + address.getText().toString()
                                + "','"
                                + pincode.getText().toString() + "')");
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                errorlbl.setText("Data Added successfully");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                errorlbl.setText(e.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }
    });

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection ConnectionHelper(){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll ()
            .build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    Connection connection = null;
    String ConnectionURL = null;
    try {
        Class.forName ("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://andridserver.... this link work fine";

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection (ConnectionURL);

        System.out.println ("Connection successful");

    }
    catch (SQLException se){
        Log.e ("error 1: ", se.getMessage ());

    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cne){
        Log.e ("error 2 :", cne.getMessage ());
    }

    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e ("error 3 :", e.getMessage ());
    }
    return connection;
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you trying to create the database? Are you trying to create the database in your Azure server? In that case, did you verify that the application has the credentials that are required for accessing the server?

Comment: I have already created the database in my Azure server. Now I want to create a table in that database. As I mentioned earlier, I can connect with my database and can run the table create the query in the shell which works fine but when I run the same query in my Application it gives me the permission denied "master' error.

Comment: Then it looks like you did not set up your application to have the credentials to access your Azure server. Because when you are accessing it through the shell, the system might have the credentials stored somewhere which is actually not available in the application that you are running. Try to put the credentials using the library functions provided by Azure.

Comment: Would you please provide me the link?
By the way, I have added my PC IP in the Server firewall.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of authentication you are using. I would recommend searching for the authentication library in Google. I found one here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users